python subprocess pending on running a nohup bash script
Given the following code example:
# save as test.py
import subprocess as sp
import time

script = '''#!/bin/bash
nohup sleep 10 &
'''

with open('test.sh', 'w') as f:
    f.write(script)

start_ts = time.time()
cp = sp.run('bash test.sh', shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - start_ts:.2f}s')

When running the above code with python test.py,
what I expect is it should stop immediately,
but instead it is pending for 10s.
Why is that? How can I fix it?

sleep inherits bash's stdout (nohup doesn't redirect it since it's not connected to a terminal) and keeps the subprocess pipe alive. Try capture_output=False or sleep 10 >/dev/null 2>&1 &.

@oguzismail redirect stdio do solve the problem.

shell=True is rarely the right thing to do, though sometimes, such as here, it doesn't actually break anything.  That causes Python to run the specified command via a shell, instead of directly.  You need it if the command you give uses shell-specific syntax, such as piping or heredocs or other redirections.  Otherwise, it's needless and occasionally problematic.
